# Unable to create partition when installing RHEL 5.8

Tags: rhel, partition, gpt

I am trying to install `RHEL 5.8` on my IBM server. When I try to create a partition manually, I get the following error message.

> Your boot partition is on a disk using the GPT partition.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you using to create your partitions?

Comment: At the time of installation, when I reach at partition option then I select **Create Custom Layout**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your IBM server has a GPT partition table and  `anaconda` - the installer - doesn't support GPT disks in your version.

You need to decide whether there is anything on the disk that is needed.  If not, you need to completely wipe the disk and start again.

The generic way to do this would be:

Boot with the install media, enter `linux rescue` mode. You should get a shell prompt.  From there:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=dev/sda bs=1024 count=1
```

should clear the boot record of `/dev/sda`.

Note: Any LiveCD distro will do.

And, of course, be aware that **this will delete everything**! All your partitions and the data on them will be lost and the disk will look like a new, unused, disk to the installer; so make sure you're happy to do this before entering the command above.

If you attempt to install again, `anaconda` will create an `MSDOS` partition table for you and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a bug in RHEL 5.8, mentioned in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/5.8_Technical_Notes/index.html:

> When installing Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 on a machine that had
>   previously used a GPT partitioning table, Anaconda does not provide
>   the option to remove the previous disk layout and is unable to remove
>   the previously used GPT partitioning table. To work around this issue,
>   switch to the tty2 terminal (using CTRL+ALT+F2), execute the following
>   command, and restart the installation process:
>
> `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/USED_DISK count=512`